# I can't reinstall mscorefonts

Tags: 14.04

I need to use Times New Roman Font. I've followed the instructions to install/reinstall mscorefonts installer. I am asked to accept EULA but when I hit ENTER nothing happens.

What should I do to finish reinstall process?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to press the `TAB` key and then on the option you want (probably the `YES` or `OK` button), you have to press the `Enter` key.

Image:
[image: Aren't cats cute?]

Comment: It worked, thanks a lot! Yet I don't see Times New Roman among the installed fonts on Writer. Is there anything I've done wrongly?

Comment: @Paul You mean "Writer" or "LibreOffice Writer"?

Comment: Sorry. LibreOffice Writer...

Comment: Move your font to ~/.fonts, and then right click and "Install Fonts".

Comment: How to mark it as "accepted"? This is my first comment...

Comment: @Paul On my question, click the button under the ^ v thing.